# MySQL query finding matches across multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, `Data(Name, dataID)` and `Attributes(Name, attributeID, dataID)` with a one-to-many relationship. One `dataID` might be associated with many `attributeID`'s.

What I want to do is run a query that finds all dataIDs that have a specific set of attributeIDs. I can't do:

```
SELECT dataID
FROM Attributes
WHERE dataID = 1 AND (attributeID = 1 OR attributeID = 2 OR attributeID = 3);
```

That would grab all dataID's with any one of those attributes, I want the dataID's that have all of those attributes.

Suggestions?

Still wrapping my head around queries using more than very basic selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to read three different rows of the `Attributes` table, I suggest to use `JOIN`'s to avoid subqueries.

```
SELECT a1.dataID
FROM
    Attributes a1
    JOIN Attributes a2 ON
        a1.dataID=a2.dataID
    JOIN Attributes a3 ON
        a2.dataID=a3.dataID
WHERE
    a1.dataID = 1 AND
    a1.attributeID = 1 AND
    a2.attributeID = 2 AND
    a3.attributeID = 3;
```

Comment: Remove the brace at the end.

Comment: This did the trick. I thought the solution would involve a join but wasn't sure just how it would be formatted. This showed me the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Though this a brute force solution, it will work using `EXISTS`. Waiting for a better solution.

```
SELECT a.dataID 
FROM DataID a WHERE a.dataID = 1 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Attributes d WHERE d.DataID = 1 AND d.attributeID = 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Attributes d WHERE d.DataID = 1 AND d.attributeID = 2)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Attributes d WHERE d.DataID = 1 AND d.attributeID = 3)
```

A `GROUP BY` solution is possible.

```
SELECT dataID 
FROM Attributes 
WHERE dataID = 1 AND (attributeID = 1 OR attributeID = 2 OR attributeID = 3)
GROUP BY dataID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: I believe you have the tables backwards.  Get from `Data` where there is a matching `Attribute` of type 1, and also of type 2.  Note that you need `D.DataID = A.DataID` in your `EXISTS` clauses.

Comment: Not quite, you're now joining `Attributes` against itself.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Isn't that what we need here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I can get both to work but they are quite slow on my rather large dataset. Still, looking at how you did this was helpful, shows me other possible approaches.